# FormData FileList is returnig as [Object FileList]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multipartform-data

It's a simple FileList of images.

```
Object.keys(pet).forEach((key) => {
      if (key === "images") {
        formData.append("images", pet[key]); //my fileList
      } else {
        formData.append(key, pet[key]);
      }
    });
```

Console.log of this FileList >>
[image]

But when I try to access the same fileList at the back-end, it shows an empty array...

```
const images = req.files;
console.log(images); // equals to []
```

And when I tried like this:

```
const images = req.body.images;
console.log(images); // Returns this: [object FileList].
```

When I use this same endpoint with Postman works perfectly...

Answer (score 3):

Just found out what was going on... I was passing an Object Array that contains a FileList that is anothar Array so it was never going to work...

```
 Object.keys(pet).forEach((key) => {
      if (key === "images") {
        let images = Array.from(pet.images[0]); //needed to access the first array first
        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          formData.append("images", images[i]);
        }
      } else {
        formData.append(key, pet[key]);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think, you also need to use it like "images[]" inside the for loop i think.